# Post a Facebook Story as map with C# is not working

Tags: c#, facebook, windows-phone-7, facebook-graph-api, facebook-c#-sdk

I am trying to post a Facebook story with a map attachement. I can post the story successfully, but the attachement is not shown as map.
I am using the Facebook C# SDK (http://facebooksdk.net/).

This is how I set up the story:
[image]

The custom object is set up with a custom property called geolocation, on which i reffer in the attachement configuration of my story:
[image]

And this is how I set the parameters for the FB post call:

```
parameters["location"] = new Dictionary<string, object>();
((Dictionary<string, object>)parameters["location"])["title"] = "Title";
((Dictionary<string, object>)parameters["location"])["geolocation:latitude"] = pokk.Location.Latitude.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
((Dictionary<string, object>)parameters["location"])["geolocation:longitude"] = pokk.Location.Longitude.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

The story is posted successfully, but this is how it looks like:
[image]

I hope you can help me..

Thanx in advance!
Greets!

Comment: I implemented something similar for a webapp and it had same display issues in timeline. Best is you create a bug report here: https://developers.facebook.com/x/bugs/created/ Looks like there are still alot bugs with fb actions, collections and stories.

Comment: Have you had a chance too look at the solution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have spent the last couple hours trying to diagnose this issue and came up with a solution however the code changes quite abit. Basically the first thing you can do is actually set the property "location" to be required. You will notice that once you set it as required that the Graph API is failing due to a required property missing.

This is a good sign, it means that something is not quite right with the submission. After digging around and manually creating objects in the `Object Browser` I came up with a solution. Now it is worth noting that I am using `dnyamic` `ExpandoObjects` instead of dictionaries but the concept is the same. Review the commented code

```
//create our location object
dynamic locationData = new ExpandoObject();
locationData.title = "sample app testing " + DateTime.Now.ToString();

//create our geolocation object
dynamic geoData = new ExpandoObject();
geoData.latitude = 37.416382;
geoData.longitude = -122.152659;
geoData.altitude = 42; //<-- important altitude figure

//create our geo data item container and add the geoData object to the geolocation property
dynamic geoDataItem = new ExpandoObject();
geoDataItem.geolocation = geoData;

//set the data property of our location data to the geo data item container
locationData.data = geoDataItem;

//create our root object setting the location property to the location data object
dynamic objItem = new ExpandoObject();
objItem.location = locationData;

var response = context.Client.Post("me/<my_app_name>:<app_action>", objItem);
```

Really all we are doing is creating a simple structure using the expando object. Where I personally got stuck what not understanding how the complete `GeoPoint` operates. If you notice we have to create 2 containers.

One container so we can set the `geolocation` property on the `data` property of the location object.

The final structure resembles

```
--- MyStory
    --- location
        --- title : 'Sample app testing....'
        --- data 
            --- geolocation
                --- latitude  : 37.416...
                --- longitude : -122.1526...
                --- altitude  : 42
```

This does seem rather complex but here is a final output preview.

[image]

Comment: Great! Thanks for your solution! It is working! Somehow I missed the "data" tag of my location object... Just a last question: can I influence the zoom of the map???

Comment: Yes the zoom is based on the altitude property on your GeoPont. In the example would be geoData.altitude. This sets the zoom height on the map

Comment: Too bad I missed the bounty. Ohh well glad the solution works.

Comment: Ah sorry for that.. I would send you the bounty manually if this would be possible.. :(..